# .font is not convertible to .font

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am taking a Swift UI tutorial and I came across this error while the instructor did not. The .font error occurs only 1 time in the first Vstack while the second time there was no issue.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var title: String = ""
    @State var rating = 3.0
    @State var seen = false

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Title")
                    .font(.subheadline)       
                    .foregroundColor(.grey)
                TextField($title)
                }
            }
            Section {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Rating").font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                    Text(String(repeating:"*", count:Int(rating)))
                Slider(value: $rating, from: 1.0, through: 5.0, by: 
        1.0).font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }

         }.listStyle(.grouped)
       }
    }

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

```
Tracker/ContentView.swift:22:28: 'Font' is not convertible to 
'Font?'
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what your actual question is. Are you looking for help with fixing something? Do you just want to understand why the error happened?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While I've been as guilty as others with criticism about a question, this is not the case. A typo isn't what anyone would expect to produce your error. First thing for you, a new contributor, is to understand two things - (1) you're dealing with an *extreme* beta product and most (all?) of us have realized the quire a few error menages are, well, *extremely* misleading - at this point. (2) Another new contributo may have the answer... and please, **never** forget that you are working with a beta product.

Answer (score 6):

This is a misleading error. The issue doesn't have anything to do with `Font`. The issue is that you have a typo:

```
Text("Title")
    .font(.subheadline)       
    .foregroundColor(.grey)
```

The `foregroundColor` should be `.gray` not `.grey`.